# O correto é "Risco de Morte" ou "Risco de Vida"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras

É muito comum ver placas em metrôs ou estações de rede elétrica, aqui no Brasil, uma placa escrita "Risco de Morte", como no exemplo abaixo.

[image: Risco de morte! Alta tensão]

O engraçado é que, quando se trata de anunciar algo que queira passar a mesma ideia de "perigo, você pode morrer", usa-se o termo "Risco de Vida".

Inclusive tem um amigo meu costumava dizer: "Se é risco de vida, então  não é risco. Porque vida é bom."

Veja:

[image]

Entendo que essa placa quer dizer : "Se você chegar aqui perto, você tem alguma chance morrer, então tome cuidado".

Mas qual delas seria o correto? "Risco de morte" é bem claro, mas "Risco de vida" soa estranho, já que estamos querendo alertar alguém sobre a morte!

Comment: Não sei o motivo, não tenho fontes confiáveis, mas a expressão é uma contração de "risco de perder a vida".

Comment: @bigown faz muito sentido, mas a contração é engraçada

Comment: Interessante que não é "risco à vida".

Comment: Antigamente na Globo eles anunciavam "risco de morte" ao se referir à alguém hospitalizado com chances de morrer ("o estado dele é gravíssimo e corre risco de morte"). Lá por 2002 eles trocaram por "risco de vida". Não sei o por quê da súbita troca.

Comment: Fala-se "risco de vida", mas é um encurtamento de "risco de perder a vida". Puristas não gostam da expressão pois a entendem literalmente.

Answer (score 12):

As duas expressões estão corretas e estão ambas em uso pelo menos desde o século XVI. A expressão *risco de morte* é mais fácil de analisar, pois podemos parafraseá-la por *risco de morrer*, enquanto *risco de vida* não é *risco de viver*. Mas *risco de vida* é logo o primeiro exemplo dado pelo dicionário Houaiss (abreviaturas desabreviadas):

> **1 risco** *s. m.* **1** probabilidade de perigo, geralmente com ameaça física para o homem e/ou para o meio ambiente <*risco de vida*> <*risco de infeção*> <*risco de contaminação*>

Note-se que os outros dois exemplos seguem o modelo de *risco de morte*: *risco de infeção* é o *risco de infetar*, é o *risco de contaminação* é o *risco de contaminar*. Em *risco de morte*, *risco de infeção* e *risco de contaminação*, a preposição *de* introduz o tipo de risco, a ameaça a que se está sujeito.

Mas a preposição *de* é muito versátil, e em *risco de vida* podemos interpretá-la como exprimindo inerência, pertença: o risco na vida. A expressão *risco de vida* é assim análoga a *fragilidade da vida*. Se foi assim que os nossos antepassados pensaram, não sei dizer, mas encontramos no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) a expressão *risco de vida* e outras semelhantes desde o século XVI. Na literatura, *risco de vida* é até mais comum, até ao presente, que *risco de morte*, e no fundo é isso, mais do que qualquer análise, que justifica a expressão. Exemplos:

> [...] o próprio António de Saldanha correu ***risco de sua pessoa***, por acudir a um homem, e não escapou dos negros, senão ferido em um braço. [João de Barros (1496-1570), *Décadas da Ásia, Década Primeira*]
>
> [...] porque a dorida e lastimosa nova do principe ja ser morto, poderia ser que sabendo-a doutrem seria ***risco de suas vidas***, lha quis dar primeiro que ninguem. [Garcia de Resende, *Vida e feitos d'el-rey Dom João Segundo*, 1533]
>
> Onde estão os pobres homens, que transfegão pelo mundo com tanto ***risco de suas almas, & vidas***? [Amador Arrais, *Diálogos*, 1589]

Há no entanto casos em que dificilmente se poderia substituir *risco de morte* por *risco de vida*, nomeadamente quando quantificamos o risco de morrer ou com *risco de morte por [qualquer causa]*:

> Segundo os cientistas de a Universidade da Califórnia em San Francisco, o fumo passivo aumenta em 30% o ***risco de morte*** por doenças de o coração. [Folha de São Paulo, 1994]
>
> As companhias de seguros utilizam estas tabelas de vida para fazer uma estimativa do ***risco de morte*** [Enciclopédia [(Corpus do Português)](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/)]

Comment: Eu acho que é uma simplificação de "risco de perder a vida". No hospital ninguém diz "Ele está em risco de morte" e sim "Ele está em risco de vida", foi só mais um exemplo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pode ser que seja. Mas nós econtramos bem cedo *risco de sua pessoa*, que é difícil de parafrasear em *risco de perder a sua pessoa*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas a expressão *risco de perder sua vida* encontra-se com frequência no século XVI.

Comment: Durante minha vida inteira eu só ouvia "risco de vida", até q alguém (provavelmente da Rede Globo) veio c/ essa história de q não tem como "correr risco de viver" e "risco de morte" começou a pipocar pra td qt é lugar.

Answer (score 5):

Comecemos por ***risco de morte***. Esta expressão é parafraseável por *risco de morrer*, ou seja, *probabilidade/possibilidade de morrer*, sendo a principal diferença entre *probabilidade* e *risco* o facto de *risco* poder apenas ser usado com situações indesejáveis. O argumento de *risco*, introduzido por *de*, tem de representar um evento, mudança de estado, ou estado futuro indesejável quando inclui uma oração:

> Duplicou o risco de morrer.
>   Duplicou o risco de que morra.
>   Duplicou o risco de o país ficar ingovernável.
>   *Duplicou o risco de estar morto.
>   *Duplicou o risco de o país ser ingovernável.
>   ??Duplicou o risco de o país estar ingovernável.
>   Duplicou o risco de o país vir a estar ingovernável.
>   *Duplicou o risco de vivermos.

Se por outro lado o sintagma proposicional incluir não uma oração, mas um sintagma nominal, a leitura é aproximadamente equivalente a *risco de X ocorrer*, *risco de passar a um estado de X*, quando é possível.

> Duplicou o risco de *morte*.
>   Duplicou o risco de *ingovernabilidade*.
>   *Duplicou o risco de *feiúra*.
>   *Duplicou o risco de *indesejabilidade*.

Existem contudo casos em que a ideia de futuro está mais esbatida, como *risco de pobreza*, *risco de desemprego*, estas expressões são antes índices, parafraseáveis por *frequência de situações de pobreza/desemprego*.

Depois, temos expressões como ***risco do novo empreendimento***, ***risco de crédito***. Embora ligeiramente diferentes,  *de* introduz em ambas a *fonte* do risco — o risco de o novo empreendimento falhar, o risco de o crédito não ser pago.

Passemos então para ***risco de vida***. Creio que a leitura mais fácil é ler *risco de vida* como *risco para a vida*, i.e., *vida* é a entidade ameaçada pelo risco, o tema do risco. Nos exemplos que o Jacinto dá, *de* pode ser substituído por *para*. Como neste caso já não estamos a falar da probabilidade de um dado evento futuro ocorrer, mas sim de uma ameaça para uma entidade:

> Aumentou/Agravou-se o risco de vida.
>   *O risco de vida aumentou em 30%.
>   ??O risco de vida duplicou.

Procurei outros exemplos modernos deste uso no CETEMPúblico e não encontrei nenhum. É possível que seja apenas um uso cristalizado de *de*, substituído hodiernamente por *para*.

Answer (score 0):

Todas as línguas têm suas expressões idiomáticas que não passariam em uma análise lógica ou semântica.  Um bom exemplo disso é quando dizemos "pois não", em pt-BR, e isso significa um "sim".  Conforme foi mencionado em um comentário, "risco de vida" pode ser explicado como "risco de perder a vida", "por a vida em risco".  Mas mesmo que não tivesse uma explicação, **o uso popular consagra qualquer expressão, faça ela sentido ou não**. Em pt-BR, noventa e nove por cento da população usa ou está habituado ao termo "risco de vida".  Porque então dizer "risco de morte"?  Só para ser diferente?