# De onde vem o «correr» de «correr risco» e «correr perigo»?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Esta [pergunta sobre o *risco de vida* e *risco de morte*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/o-correto-%C3%A9-risco-de-morte-ou-risco-de-vida) deixou-me a pensar sobre as expressões ***correr risco*** e ***correr perigo***. O [Aulete traz o significado relevante de correr:](http://www.aulete.com.br/correr)

> **7.** Estar exposto a (perigo ou risco) [td. : *O telhado, malconservado, corre o risco de desabar*.]

Donde vem este uso de *correr*? O uso parece-me idiomático: não vejo relação entre ele e os significados comuns de *correr*. É curioso que no inglês se usa a expressão equivalente *run the risk*; *run the danger* também se encontra, mas é muito menos comum (ver [esta pergunta no ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70492/is-run-the-danger-in-common-usage)). *Risk* e *risco* vem ambos do italiano via francês (Houaiss e [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/risk)). Será que o *correr* de *correr risco* já vem também do francês ou italiano?

Portanto a pergunta é: quando é que aparecem as expressões *correr risco* e *correr perigo*, e donde vem esse uso de *correr*?

Comment: É uma fase em inglês também e tem origin de ao menos as 1600s: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/run--a--risk...  Quero saber também!

Comment: @robertotomás [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=risk) diz que *run the risk* é de 1660s. *Correr o risco* já se usava pelo menos em 1570 [(vê esta resposta)](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/o-correto-%C3%A9-risco-de-morte-ou-risco-de-vida/3241#3241)

Answer (score 5):

*Caveat emptor*: não sou etimologista nem lingusta, só um curioso.

Eu tenho uma teoria.

A expressão *correr risco* existe em todas as linguas latinas que conheço: [Corre el riesgo](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=correr%20el%20riesgo) (ES), [correre il rischio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rischio_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) (IT) e [courir le risque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/courir_le_risque) (FR) e isso me fez pensar que seu uso tem alguma origem comum, provavelmente no latim. Acontece que se procurarmos por *currere periculum*, que é o verbo latino para correr, não se encontra a expressão em nenhuma referência on-line. Isso me fez pensar que talvez seja alguma distorção que, com o tempo, se transformou em "correr".

Em [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) há a raiz [*ḱers-](http://www.palaeolexicon.com/ShowWord.aspx?Id=19498), que quer dizer correr. Em proto-itálico virou *korzo até que chegou ao latim *curro* (inf. *currere*). No latim a palavra foi eventualmente prefixada com in, virando incurro que, assim como em português, significa "ir/correr ao encontro ao". Dessa maneira não é difícil ver uma relação muito próxima (quase cognática) de correr com incorrer.

Agora sim, buscando por livros latinos mais antigos, as expressões [incurro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=TalJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=incurro%20periculum&source=bl&ots=_1HE6FD3ED&sig=VGpc3_MZXXb-6hKS9rmPgRXGr_4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYsN2P7vXMAhVkyoMKHaRLB10Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=incurro%20periculum&f=false) (primeira pessoa) / [incurrere](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Os8r5L3_GbQC&pg=PA642&lpg=PA642&dq=incurrere%20periculum&source=bl&ots=9aEX_sbmZ3&sig=0zT-bwowENglGCwshfysJXIEYqs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIuLfq7fXMAhUH6YMKHfDMAZwQ6AEINTAI#v=onepage&q=incurrere%20periculum&f=false) (infinitivo) periculum são encontradas com alguma frequencia.

Com tudo isso em vista, eu chutaria que houve um intercâmbio no uso da palavra correr com o sentido de incorrer, de modo que o "ir de encontro ao risco" do latim virou "correr (ao) risco" nas linguas latinas.

Mas atenção: Como usei o Google Books para procurar e só vi livros de 1600 e 1700, posso estar correndo o risco (há!) de ter como fonte livros que foram traduzidos ipsi litteris de linguas latinas para o latim. Há que se pesquisar livros mais antigos para validar essa minha teoria.

Já para o inglês eu acredito que é somente uma apropriação do francês. Pode-se ver no Ngram que a expressão run the risk [só aparece com mais força em meados do Século XVIII](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run%20the%20risk&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crun%20the%20risk%3B%2Cc0), uma época onde a influência francesa era muito forte. A mesma pesquisa para o francês mostra que essa expressão já era usada pelo menos uns 100 anos antes.

Comment: Acho que acertaste na muche com a origem comum. Mas as várias fontes que consultei dizem que a origem de *risco* e cognatos é o italiano, não diretamente o latim. Vê [este site francês](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/risque) muito completo. Será que *correr o risco* veio também do italiano? Conseguiste apurar quando é que se começou a usar *correr risco* e *correr perigo* em português?